# How can I tell if a decimal number represented as a String will fit in a double?

Tags: java, types, casting, double, bigdecimal

I'm parsing a String value which I know contains a number.

If it only contains digits and it's between Integer.MIN_VALUE and Integer.MAX_VALUE I'm parsing it as an int, similarly for long otherwise I'm using BigInteger.

If it contains a decimal value I'd either like to parse it as a double or as a BigDecimal.

Can I test if the numeric value in the String "fits" into a double and is therefore safe to parse as a double, or whether it needs to be held in a BigDecimal to prevent loss of precision?

Comment: Would new Integer(String) work? If it throws an exception, you could try another option

Comment: As a general rule, your life will almost certainly be much simpler if you just stick to one numeric type.  If you've got a String that can represent an arbitrary decimal number, use `BigDecimal` instead of trying to switch between `int`, `BigInteger`, `long`, `double`, `BigDecimal`.  Trying to switch types adds complexity that almost never actually gives meaningful benefit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> and is therefore safe to parse as a double, or whether it needs to be held in a BigDecimal to prevent loss of precision?

This won't be the answer that you're looking for, but since you seem to be concerned about loss of precision, you should use a `BigDecimal` in place of any `double`.

The number `0.1` can *fit* in a `double`, but it isn't precise (as `0.1` can not be represented accurately in binary).

See: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 0):

The `Double` class contains these constants:

```
public static final double MIN_VALUE = 0x0.0000000000001P-1022; // 4.9e-324
public static final double MAX_VALUE = 0x1.fffffffffffffP+1023; // 1.7976931348623157e+308
```

you could use them to perform your checks if you can.  
But wouldn't it be easier just a `try/catch` block:

```
String str = "1234567890";
double number = 0;
try {
    number = Double.parseDouble(str);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    // put extra code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would parse it as a BigDecimal and then check whether double can store the value without a loss of information to an acceptable degree.